# How to create app-like Chrome shortcuts?

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

I have a Chrome application which, at some point, I added to my home screen and it was behaving like a real application: there was no Chrome toolbar (for the URL and other settings). The icon was also a "native one" (the difference will be clear in a second).

For various reasons I removed it from my home screen and also upgraded to Pie (I am not sure if this matters).

I then tried to re-create the "app" by adding, from Chrome, a shortcut to my home screen. This is how it looks now:

[image]

Please note the Chrome thumbnail which was not there previously.

The app itself does not look "native" anymore:

[image]

The part between the status bar and the blue line used not to be there, completely hiding the fact that this is a web page running in Chrome.

**What is the correct way to get back this "native app" behaviour?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wait for the web app developer to implement [Chrome's WebAPK on Android](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks) feature/requirements.

From the following post: [How to Remove Chrome Logo from PWA App Home Screen Link (Android O Preview)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44060253/295004)

Digging through the comments on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761109/295004) from [Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057093/anand) dated Dec 17, 2018:

> If you are asking how to avoid chrome icon, as long as your went [*sic*] app is fully qualifies PWA to be installed as APK, new versions of chrome won't add that icon. I've tested with chrome version 70 in Android pie . If it's a mere web page, failing to meet key PWA criteria or non PWA, chrome might add chrome icon to indicate it's a web link(depending on chrome version again)

Further research on details led me down a [rabbit hole](https://medium.com/@firt/is-there-a-cold-war-between-android-and-chrome-because-of-pwas-e50a7471056c) of what features exist on Chrome vs Android and the meaning of 'install' to home screen, which while it does somewhat affect end-user behavioral expectations, the implementation details are off-topic for this site.

If you can live with icon badging, you may want to try your site/webapp with [Firefox for Android](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/progressive-web-apps-firefox-android/) and see if the app UI still retains the undesirable "header".

Comment: Thank you. Are you aware of changes in the API which would led to a page being PWA-compatible to lose this compatibility when going from Oreo to Pie?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't know. Assuming that nothing changed on the site, looking through: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/ it does mention `Meets a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds)` so you can try uninstalling, interact with site for more than a minute and try to reinstall and see if that helps. Otherwise its up to when you installed with x version of Chrome and now on y version of Chrome, Google has refined the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your help - it pushed me to the solution (which I posted as well for completeness). It was my fault and your pointer to the PWA standards made me release my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being a lack of HTTPS. @Morisson's answer pushed me to the right direction and I realized, "temporary for testing purposes", that I have removed HTTPS for the site.

Back to HTTPS, I can create a PWA out of the site again.